# If Brahman is everything, then why does Krishna (Brahman) describe himself as "best of things" in Bhagavadgita?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, brahman

Supreme Brahman is everything. He has two forms: Manifest and Unmanifest. All dualities such as good&bad, evil&virtue are indeed Supreme Brahman's MAYA.

Krishna describes Himself as Positive entities of all dualities, deliberately leaving negative entities. For Example,

[Bhagavad Gita 10.22](http://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-10-22/#more-607)

> vedānāḿ sāma-vedo ’smi
>
> devānām asmi vāsavaḥ
>
> indriyāṇāḿ manaś cāsmi
>
> bhūtānām asmi cetanā
>
> Of the Vedas I am the Sama Veda; of the demigods I am Indra, the king
>   of heaven; of the senses I am the mind; and in living beings I am the
>   living force [consciousness].

[Bhagavad Gita 10.23](http://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-10-23/)

> rudrāṇāḿ śańkaraś cāsmi
>
> vitteśo yakṣa-rakṣasām
>
> vasūnāḿ pāvakaś cāsmi
>
> meruḥ śikhariṇām aham
>
> Of all the Rudras I am Lord Shankara, of
>   the Yakshas and Rakshasas I am the Lord of wealth [Kuvera], of the
>   Vasus I am fire [Agni], and of mountains I am Meru.

Here, Lord Krishna says He is Kubera. All Raksasas are indeed born from Supreme Brahman indirectly. But Krishna describes himself as Kubera who is good. All Vedas are emanated from Brahman but Krishna says He is Samaveda. Similarly in all verses he describes himself as strongest or best of things.

If we assume Krishna (or Vishnu) as Supreme Brahman (no offense), then why does he describe himself as "best of things"?

Comment: "It is said in the scriptures that water is a form of God. But some water is fit to be used for worship, some water for washing the face, and some only for washing plates or dirty linen. This last sort cannot be used for drinking or for a holy purpose. In like manner, God undoubtedly dwells in the hearts of all - holy and unholy, righteous and unrighteous; but a man should not have dealings with the unholy, the wicked, the impure."  “God is in all men, but all men are not in God" -Ramakrishna Paramhans

Comment: @RaviJ What has that quote to do with the above question?

Comment: Water is present everywhere, in toilets, sewers etc., but it is unfit to drink, as water from Ganga or filter is best. In the similar way God has become everything even dog, Chandal etc., but it is in sages,demigods and rishis(where Satva dominates) that God manifests most. It is about positive and negative vibrations. If you think about God, temples, etc.,, than ofcourse your positive vibrations will increase that will take you to divine but if you remain among womanizers, alcoholics, you will definitely increase negative vibrations that will take towards lower realms. I hope you got it.

Comment: @Chinmay, it is metaphor, that always go upwards, till the highest is not reached. Because, leader of every group is God himself. Geeta itself is crux of best of teachings of various rishis, but only Omnipotent God himself can compile them. Of course God has become the hell also, but who wants to live in hell, other than if some one has personal choice.

Comment: @RaviJ I agree with you and that's what our Sanatana Dharma says unlike Abrahamic Religions. But a newbie would infer that Good alone is GOD. Indeed, BAD teaches us lessons. Satva removes Vritti (impressions) in mind and helps to attain Moksha. But Raja and Tamas too should present because without them World can't run. I think Krishna deliberately didn't recount this point may be not to create confusion.

Comment: Your Q is very good. On the side note (from Gita) *sattva* helps to retain *Dharma*, but doesn't help directly in *Moksha*. Opposite, it binds *jeeva* by light & happiness. Only 'help' can be is that *sattva* is easy to adopt & later easy to drop before attaining *Moksha*. *Dharma* doesn't imply subsequent *Moksha*. Anyways this is not part of Q. BTW there are few 'bad' forms, which Krishna assumes are gambling, death, overall annihilation, kuber ... But yes they are too less compared to 'good' ones.

Answer (score 4):

Read verse 10.17:

> कथं विद्यामहमं योगिंस्त्वां परिचिन्तयन् |
>   केषु केषु च भावेषु चिन्त्योसि भगवन्मया ||

Translation from [there](http://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-10-17/):

> O Krishna, O supreme mystic, how shall I constantly think of You, and how shall I know You? **In what various forms are You to be remembered**, O Supreme Personality of Godhead?

So, you can see that Arjuna asked Krishna : "In what various forms are You to be remembered?" or (from [here](http://www.bhagavad-gita.org/Gita/verse-10-15.html)) **"In which various manifestations are You to be contemplated by me?"**

that's why Krishna is describing positively or best of things!

Comment: I didn't ask what circumstance made Krishna to say this but Why did Krishna deliberately leave negative or weak entities? Brahman is everything, both Good and Bad. But Law of nature favors Good over bad, Strong over weak.

Comment: @AnilKumar But your question seems asking why does Krishna.... Edit your question (title) to clear what you are asking

Answer (score 3):

No doubt, Brahman is everything. While reciting Bhagwat Geeta, Krishna went in union with Brahman, so whatever he spoke were actually words from Brahman itself.

This is also explained in Anu Gita from Mahabharata Book 14: [Aswamedha Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m14/)

> Then Arjuna, the son of Pându, having surveyed with delight that
>   lovely palace, in the company of Krishna, spoke these words: ‘O you of
>   mighty arms! O you whose mother is Devakî! When the battle was about
>   to commence, I became aware of your greatness, and that divine form of
>   yours. But that, O Kesava! which through affection (for me) you
>   explained before, has all disappeared, O tiger-like man! from my
>   degenerate mind. Again and again, however, I feel a curiosity about
>   those topics. But (now), O Mâdhava! you will be going at no distant
>   date to Dvârakâ.
>
> Krishna, possessed of great glory,replied in these words after
>   embracing Arjuna.
>
> Vâsudeva said: From me, O son of Prithâ! you heard a mystery, and
>   learnt about the eternal (principle), about piety in (its true) form,
>   and about all the everlasting worlds. It is excessively disagreeable
>   to me, that you should not have grasped it through want of
>   intelligence. And the recollection (of it) now again is not possible
>   (to me). Really, O son of Pându! you are devoid of faith and of a bad
>   intellect. And, O Dhanañjaya! it is not possible for me to repeat in
>   full (what I said before). For that doctrine was perfectly adequate
>   for understanding the seat, of the Brahman. It is not possible for me
>   to state it again in full in that way. **For then accompanied by my
>   mystic power, I declared to you the Supreme Brahman.**

The Nature is made of 3 gunas, but God manifests most in Satva. Brahman is beyond Prakriti and in Prakriti also. Many think that Prakriti alone has gunas, but actually Prakriti is inert without consciousness/seed/soul from Brahman i.e. Shakti of Prakriti comes from Brahman itself. In a way, Brahman and Shakti are same or more like Father and Mother.

**God manifests most in Satva**, that is the reason, in ancient times killing of Brahmin(who were Satva dominated), was regarded as biggest sin. Actually the three gunas, arranges themselves into six bands, where the person in white band(in which Satva,dominates over Rajas and Tamas) is at highest level of spirituality and nearest to Brahman. Read in Mahabharat [Moksha Dham](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b107.htm)

> The highest Evidence (for all things) says that creatures have six
>   colours, viz., Dark, Tawny, Blue, Red, Yellow, and White. These
>   colours proceed from mixtures in various proportions of the three
>   attributes of Rajas, Tamas, and Sattwa. Where Tamas predominates,
>   Sattwa falls below the mark, and Rajas keeps to the mark, the result
>   is the colour called Dark. When Tamas predominates as before, but the
>   relations between Sattwa and Rajas are reversed, the result is the
>   colour called Tawny. When Rajas predominates, Sattwa falls below the
>   mark, and Tamas keeps to the mark, the result is the colour called
>   Blue. When Rajas predominates as before and the proportion is reversed
>   between Sattwa and Tamas, the result is the intermediate colour called
>   Red. That Colour is more agreeable (than the preceding one). When
>   Sattwa predominates, Rajas falls below the mark and, Tamas keeps to
>   the mark, the result is the colour called Yellow. It is productive of
>   happiness. When Sattwa predominates and the proportion is reversed
>   between Rajas and Tamas, the result is the colour called White. It is
>   productive of great happiness. **The White is the foremost colour. It
>   is sinless in consequence of its being free from attachment and
>   aversion. It is without grief, and free from the toil involved in
>   Pravritti. Hence, White, O prince of Danavas, leads to success (or
>   Emancipation).**

Where Satva is highest, that person is definitely the leader of Group like Indra, Garuda etc.,whatever Krishna described. There is another interesting story from Gospel of Ramakrishna Paramhans discussing nature of Brahman.

> The three gunas
>
> MASTER: "Yes, it is. But that concept is something far beyond the
>   ordinary man. Daya springs from sattva. Sattva preserves, rajas
>   creates, and tamas destroys. But Brahman is beyond the three gunas. It
>   is beyond Prakriti.
>
> "None of the three gunas can reach Truth; they are like robbers, who
>   cannot come to a public place for fear of being arrested. Sattva,
>   rajas, and tamas are like so many robbers.
>
> "Listen to a story. Once a man was going through a forest, when three
>   robbers fell upon him and robbed him of all his possessions. One of
>   the robbers said, 'What's the use of keeping this man alive?' So
>   saying, he was about to kill him with his sword, when the second
>   robber interrupted him, saying: 'Oh, no! What is the use of killing
>   him? Tie him hand and foot and leave him here.' The robbers bound his
>   hands and feet and went away.
>
> After a while the third robber returned and said to the man: 'Ah, I am
>   sorry. Are you hurt? I will release you from your bonds.' After
>   setting the man free, the thief said: 'Come with me. I will take you
>   to the public highway.' After a long time they reached the road. Then
>   the robber said: 'Follow this road. Over there is your house.' At this
>   the man said: 'Sir, you have been very good to me. Come with me to my
>   house ' 'Oh, no!' the robber replied. 'I can't go there. The police
>   will know it.'
>
> This world itself is the forest. The three robbers prowling here are
>   sattva, rajas, and tamas. It is they that rob a man of the Knowledge
>   of Truth. Tamas wants to destroy him. Rajas binds him to the world.
>   But sattva rescues him from the clutches of rajas and tamas. Under the
>   protection of sattva, man is rescued from anger, passion, and the
>   other evil effects of tamas. Further, sattva loosens the bonds of the
>   world. But sattva also is a robber. It cannot give him the ultimate
>   Knowledge of Truth, though it shows him the road leading to the
>   Supreme Abode of God. Setting him on the path, sattva tells him: 'Look
>   yonder. There is your home.' Even sattva is far away from the
>   Knowledge of Brahman. Nature of Brahman cannot he described
>
> "**What Brahman is cannot be described.** Even he who knows It cannot talk
>   about It. There is a saying that a boat, once reaching the 'black
>   waters' of the ocean, cannot come back.

Bhagwat Geeta 4.6 describing nature of Brahman briefly

> Although I am unborn, the Lord of all living entities, and have an
>   imperishable nature, yet I appear in this world by virtue of Yogmaya,
>   my divine power.

Comment: I am not sure whether God mostly manifests in Satva alone. Rama, Krishna and even Parasurama though Brahmin by birth (Satva), exhibited traits  like Kshatriya (Rajas). You say Indra is Satva but Purandara is selfish which is not Satva. I think highest position of race or Group may not be a Satva always.

Answer (score 3):

Lord Krishna is indeed is the supreme Brahman is mentioned [here](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/14/27) in Bhagvad geeta.
In 10th chapter of Geeta He is mentioning only [his principle opulence](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/10/19) so that normal people could understand it; since it is not possible for us to ascertain His opulence.

> The Supreme Personality of Godhead said: Yes, I will tell you of My
>   splendorous manifestations, but only of those which are prominent, O
>   Arjuna, for My opulence is limitless.

Krishna says that he is Lion among beasts; that does not mean that every lion is Krishna or that He is banyan tree among trees similarly.
Nor does it mean that other animals or trees are not His manifestations.
All are His manifestations; either directly or indirectly... '*vāsudevaḥ sarvam iti*'(BG 7.19).
However in 10th chapter Krishna mentions **Only His principle opulence**.
How I understand it is that **He is the Best Among all and there is no one who could transcend Him in any field**.
i.e. among birds He is the best, among Daityas he is the best, among Demigods He is the best...... and there is no one greater than Him.

**For example if a rich person chooses to show off his riches ; it is most likely that he will exhibit the best of what he has; now that does not mean that he doesn't own some other things that are cheaper.**

Similarly Krishna is exhibiting His opulence here in terms of 'Best of things' in this material world; because by such explanation a mundane person like me can easily understand how great He is. Otherwise we know that He is great; but how great He is?.. that we don't know or we wont be able to know.
Also it is not that he shows only positive opulence but also negative opulence(but mostly positive and good; however good or bad; that duality is our perception.God is beyond such duality).
in BG 10.36 Lord Says

> I am also the gambling of cheats, and of the splendid I am the
>   splendor. I am victory, I am adventure, and I am the strength of the
>   strong.

Comment: True, praising oneself is a Divine quality

Comment: @amitSaxena praising the Lord is divine quality

Comment: That too! :) ...

Answer (score 2):

There are two answers to your question found in the Bhagavad Gita:

> "The Supreme Personality of Godhead said: Yes, I will tell you of My
>   splendorous manifestations, **but only of those which are prominent**, O
>   Arjuna, for My opulence is limitless." (Bhagavad Gita, 10.19)

Krsna is only referring to certain opulences of himself.

> "Know that all states of being – be they of goodness, passion or
>   ignorance – are manifested by My energy. I am, in one sense,
>   everything, but I am independent. I am not under the modes of material
>   nature, for they, on the contrary, are within Me." (Bhagavad Gita,
>   7.12)

Here Krsna clarifies that He is the unborn separate from the modes of nature.

This means that in one way everything is Krsna but in another way everything is not Krsna.

Answer (score 0):

A dualistic description of Parabrahman ("best of breed" for all categories) cannot be made unambiguous.  He says he is the Ganga among rivers, but some Southern Vaishnavites think the Kaveri is more sacred than the Ganga.  They must know the Bhagavad Gita and are Krishna devotees, but they still say that.

https://www.sadagopan.org/pdfuploads/Thirumalai%20Arivom.pdf

> Srirangam has the natural kshEtra visEsham; kAvEri
> which is flowing through this kshetram is considered holier than the Ganges;

multiple scriptures say that during an eclipse all waters become as pure as the Ganga

[Which scripture says that during eclipse all water become pure like Ganges water?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11093/which-scripture-says-that-during-eclipse-all-water-become-pure-like-ganges-water)