# Which scripture says that during eclipse all water become pure like Ganges water?

Tags: scripture, rituals, brahmins, eclipse, vashishta

Which scripture says that during eclipse all water become pure like Ganges water?

[This](http://brahminrituals.blogspot.in/2011_05_01_archive.html) page make the following claims:

> During eclipse all waters are equivalent to Ganges water and all
> Brahmins are equivalent to Vasishta.
>
> [image]

I would love to have answers to the second question as well, which is:

Which scripture claims that during eclipse all Brahmins are equivalent to Maharshi Vasishta?

**Edit**-Adding the  exact Sanskrit verses which i found on [this](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/dharmasindhu/bookview.php?chapnum=5) page:

> During the �Grahana Kaala�, Go-Bhu-Hiranyaadi Daanaas would accord
> far-reaching benefits. It is stated: **Sarvam Gangaa samam toyam, Sarvey
> Vyaasa samaah Dwijaah**, Sarvam Bhumi samam daanam grahaney Chandra
> Suryayoh/ (**On occasions like Lunar or Solar Eclipses, all kinds of
> waters are like Ganga water; all Brahmanas are like Vyasaacharya**; and
> all kinds of charity are as good as Bhu daana).

Comment: I know its futile to ask but still--Why the downvote ??

Comment: BTw,the blog states that all brahmins are like Vasishta during eclipse whereas the Sanskrit verse says like Vyasa.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Parashar Smriti, Chapter 12 [source 1](https://archive.org/stream/ParasharaSmriti/SriParasharaSmrithiPdf#page/n115/mode/2up) [source 2](https://archive.org/stream/ParasharaSmriti/SriParasharaSmrithiPdf_djvu.txt) says , during eclipse all waters become pure like Ganges.

> सर्वं गंगा समं तोयं राहुग्रस्ते दिवाकरे।
>
> सोमग्रहे तथैवोक्तं स्नानदानादि कर्मसु।।
>
> When the sun or the moon is seized by rahu, all water
> becomes as pure as the water of the Ganga, so far as bathing and giving, and other religious rites are concerned.

Comment: Hi Tryugi, I am not seeing any of ur posts these days..Why ? R u too busy? :)

Comment: @Rickross Thanks for asking. There were some extra responsibilities these days. But now I will be available and will post something.

Comment: Ok that's very good to know..

Answer (score 7):

The Katyayana Smriti also says the same :

> **During solar and lunar eclipses all the waters, that exist on earth**
>   and even that in a well, **become like that of the Ganges.**
>
> **Katyayana Smriti,Chapter 10,Verse 14**

Answer (score 7):

Padma Purana also says that during the eclipse, all waters become same like Ganges and all Brahmins become equivalent to Vyasa.

> कुर्याद्ग्रासंसैम्हिकेयस्तत्क्षणंदुर्लभंभवेत् |
>     **सर्वगङ्गासमंतोयंवेदव्यास समाद्विजाः** || Padma Purana 4.10.22
>
> Now (even) when that day arrives he fights with the Moon and the Sun. The
>   son of Simhika (i.e. Rahu) would live (in them). That would be a
>   moment difficult to secure. **(At that time) all water is like (that
>   of) Ganga, and all brahmanas are like Vyasa**. (Brahma Khanda Chapter 10 Verse 22)

Answer (score 3):

One more reference from Maya-Tantram 17th Patalam,

> तत्क्षणे सर्वतीर्थानि सामान्यमुदकं प्रिये।
> यान्ति स्वपदमृत्सृज्य सर्वतीर्थोदकं ततः॥7॥
> **सामान्यमुदकं तनु गङ्गातोयसमं भवेत्‌**॥
> तत्क्षणे चञ्जलापाङ्गि तज्जले स्नानमात्रतः॥8॥
> **चर्तुभुजसमा: सर्वे लोका भारतवासिनः**।
> तत्क्षणाद्‌ गिरिजे सत्यं मोक्ष ब्रह्मपुरं ब्रजेत्‌॥9॥
>
> > At that instance,  all of the *Tirthas* and every common source of water merges into the waters of all *Tirthas*. Water from all sources is equivalent to the Gangas. O devi, the one with agile eyes, Thus the people living in *Bharata* by merely taking bath in such waters become as if Vishnu (*Chaturbuja*= the one with four hands), attain *Moksha* and move to the *Brahmapura*.

Answer (score 2):

Skanda Mahā-Purāṇa (Verse 4.1.9.73) says - All waters during eclipse are equivalent to the Ganges water, and all Brāhmiṇas equivalent to Brahmā.

> [Chapter 9](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc423746.html), Pūrvārdha, Kāśī-khaṇḍa
>
> सर्वं गंगासमं तोयं सर्वे ब्रह्मसमा द्विजाः ।
>  सर्वं देयं स्वर्णसमं
> राहुग्रस्ते दिवाकरे ॥ ७३ ॥
>
> > 73. **When the Sun is swallowed by Rāhu (i.e., during solar eclipse) all waters are on a par with Gaṅgā, all Brāhmiṇas are on a par with Brahmā**
> >     and everything gifted equal with gold.

So, as per the Skanda Purāṇa, all waters are equal to Ganga, but all the Brāhmiṇas are equivalent to Brahmā, and not Rishi Vasistha.