# What is the reason behind Gita favoring the SAtvika way over others?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, karma, yoga, moksha, spiritual-level

Usually people who have read Gita, would say that *NishKAma Karma* is the way of "Karma yoga".
Numerous verses suggest that, *NishkAma Karma* is *SAtvika* way of life. *SakAma karma* is *RAjasika* way & *Vikarma* is *TAmasika* way. Even attempting to perform *Akarma* is also sometimes considered *TAmasika* way.

Now everyone is aware that, The supreme *Purusha / Brahman* (the ultimate "I/Me") is beyond 3 modes of nature: *Sattva, Rajas, Tamas*. **A person with any predominant quality should have the same right on Moksha**.

As discussed in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16190/1049), there is a difference between *NishkAma Karma* ("Karma Yoga") and *NishkarmatA* ("Moksha or Jeevan Mukta").

Why can't a person with RAjasika nature do "Karma yoga" with *SakAma Karma* & attain *NishkarmatA*?

Similarly, why can't a *TAmasika* person do "Karma yoga" with *Vikarma* and attain Moksha?

<sub>IMO People like ShishupAla, Hiranyakashipu, RAvana, Kamsa, who probably attained Moksha, were not doing *NishkAma Karma*.</sub>

Comment: Nishkama Karma is *one of the* way/path to Jnana/Moksha, *not only* the way to Jnana/Moksha.

Comment: Simple reason is, if everyone behaves like Ravana, there would be no humans left on Earth :P By Ravana-like actions I mean vikarma ("actions that are performed through the misuse of one's freedom and that direct one to the lower life forms")

Comment: @sv., "if everyone behaves like Ravana, there would be no humans left on Earth" - Why do you think it to be a enough reason? IMO, those who are done with the material nature (*Prakruti*) actually don't care about world. Hypothetically if anyone knows superiority of Moksha, will have no purpose to remain in the world. Actually, the world itself doesn't remain during the night of the *Brahman* (BG 8.18). Kamsa killed new borns by banging them to wall, later he got killed other new borns in city. But no scripture supporting of him getting lower life for cruelty. Rather some say, he got Moksha.

Comment: @iammilind Kamsa, Ravana etc. could be exceptions but if everyone tries to emulate them, Earth won't be a sustainable place. I think BG recognizes the fact not everyone can attain moksha in their current lifetime which is why it's favoring sadācāra over other ways.

Comment: @sv. According to BG 9.7, "at the end of Brahman's day, everything assumes 'My' nature". From verse BG 14.2, "assuming 'My' nature is the supreme state". So to me, at least in that context, Moksha seems guaranteed for everyone. For its logical reasoning, you may also refer [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/10746/1049). Let's move to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49462/what-exactly-is-a-leela).

Comment: Related [If Brahman is everything, then why does Krishna (Brahman) describe himself as “best of things” in Bhagavadgita?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11090/3500)

Comment: you are confusing and making false equivalencies with different terms together. The three gunas, sattva, rajas, and tamas, are qualities that make up Maya. Everything is a combination of these three. Since we are a part of Maya, everyone is a combination of the three gunas. Everyone has in different combinations, and one guna can predominate in a single person at different times. The gunas are not 'ways' in the sense that the yogas - karma, raja, bhakti, and jnana - are ways to God.

Comment: It is possible to be a tamasic bhakta and realize God. It is possible to practice Jnana Yoga with a rajasic attitude. All combinations are possible. See Gita 9.30

Comment: @Swami ji, Every entity has these 3 modes more or less. They always keep competing with each other. Sometimes *sattva* is high, sometimes *rajas* & *tamas* as well. Having said above, if you refer BG 2.47 or BG 6.1 then it describes ["Karma yoga"] as renouncing the reactions (*Karma fala*). That leads to final destination (*parama gati*). Now if you refer BG 18.9, then it refers such renunciation of reactions as *SAtvika*! Why "karma yoga" has striking similarities with *SAtvika* ways? --- is my Qn. BTW I don't relate 3 modes with various yoga-s (*karma, dhyAna, gyAna*; & *bhakti* isn't yoga).

Answer (score 4):

Because Satva Guna helps in approaching spirituality thought it doesn't lead one to Moksha.

See the nature of three Gunas as described in Bhagavag Gita

> 14.11 When the illumination that is knowledge radiates in this body through all the doors (of the senses), then one should know that sattva has increased greatly.
>
> 14.12 O best of the Bharata dynasty, when rajas becomes predominant, these come into being: avarice, movement, undertaking of actions, unrest and hankering.
>
> 14.13 O descendant of the Kuru dynasty, when tamas predominates these surely [i.e. without exception.-M.S.] come into being: non-discrimination and inactivity, inadvertence and delusion.

Also see the next birth according to the dominance of particular Guna while departure:

Satva : attains the taintless worlds of those who know the highest
Rajas : born among people *attached* to activity
Tamas : birth among the stupid species.

> 14.18 People **who conform to sattva go higher up**; those who conform to rajas stay in the middle; those who conform to tamas, who conform to the actions of the lowest ality, go down.

So, it's very obvious that there are very less chances of obtaining true knowledge for the followers of Rajas and Tamas Gunas. Agree that Satva Guna will not lead one to Moksha, for approaching Moksha, one needs to go beyond all three Gunas. As preached in 14.6th verse : "it binds through attachment to happiness and attachment to knowledge." However it is better than Rajas and Tamas as it helps in purifying mind and in becoming eligible for one to obtain the true knowledge.

> **Q.** Why can't a person with RAjasika or TAmasika nature do "Karma yoga" with SakAma Karma & attain Moksha?

As mentioned above, Rajasika or Tamasika mind is not eligible to understand or obtain the right knowledge that is required for Moksha. So, regarding your queries you can consider that Rajasika or Tamasika Sakama Karma Yoga is wrong tool which will never lead one to Moksha and comparatively Satviak Nishkama Karma is preferable (right tool) which can lead one to the Moksha.