# Why choose doing "good" when there is no ultimate good or evil?

Tags: philosophy, karma, evil

Why should one choose to do good over evil? Maybe your evil is my good and your good is my evil? There is no ultimate good or evil, so whats the reason to do "good" deeds then?

All ways lead to God, if you deny this you deny the oneness of God and the Unity of God. So doing "evil" should be just as valid as doing "Good"?

Comment: Because the "ultimate" is a state to be reached through industry and penance. Until that state is reached,  good and evil definitely exist. Besides, the ends don't justify the means.

Comment: Related [What is the reason behind Gita favoring the SAtvika way over others?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16201/277)

Comment: But if you reach the ultimate. Still what you do will be either good or evil in the eyes of a person that has not reached that state. When one is free from all labels, why can such a person commit evil without that being evil, but when someone that hasn't reach that state does it is considered evil and "punished" by karma. This is very weird....

Comment: Person who has reached that state do not perform evil. Every avatara adhered to dharma in spite of hardships.

Comment: But that's the thing. He could do it if he wants to, so why should we say he does not perform evil. He could perform it in such a state also if he so chooses.

Comment: Then he would no longer be the satchidananda parabramha. Evil doers are just that; they are not god. And this discipline and will to do only good is what distinguishes god from evil.

Comment: True, ultimately there is no good or bad. Each one of his creations has to reach him. But the time it takes to reach him from this instant may be: this birth, the next, a hundred more or an aeon or more. This is because, we have to experience the fruits of karma till there is nothing to be experienced. Meaning, we must rise beyond bad and good. This is only possible by reaching the state of non-doership, or by attributing every action of ours to him. Therefore, clearly there is no good or no bad, it’s all a play of the almighty, where you have got no choices.

Comment: would you prefer if someone fed you bread, or poison ? whatever is your honest answer, do the same to others. similarly, if you want people to do you 'evil', do others 'evil'. The meaning of 'No ultimate good or evil' is that whatever good or evil you do will not go waste i.e. it will be returned to you, so the sum total of good & evil will become zero. So, if you want to be killed, kill. If you want to live, let others live.