# in which verse of gita, has krishna declared that he is shiva, vishnu, brahma, devi & supreme

Tags: vishnu, shiva, bhagavad-gita, brahma, devi

1. Shiva:
   In which verse of gita, krishna has declared  either that krishna is "shiva" or declared that "shiva" origiates from him?
2. Vishnu:
   In which verse of gita , krishna has declared  either that krishna is "vishnu" or declared that "vishnu" origiates from him?
3. Brahma:
   In which verse of gita, krishna has declared  either that krishna is "brahma" or declared that "brahma" origiates from him?
4. Devi/Shakti:
   In which verse of gita, krishna has declared  either that devishakti operates/originates under him? or He is himself shakti?
5. Krishna is supreme form:
   In which verse of gita and scriptures, krishna has declared  either that krishna is the most complete/supreme form out of all the these trimurti

Comment: Partial duplicate or Related: [Are there any scriptural references of the trinity "Brahma, Vishnu, Mahesh(Shiva)" as depicted in popular culture?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20599/are-there-any-scriptural-references-of-the-trinity-brahma-vishnu-maheshshiva). (1),(2),(3) are answered in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/21205/1049). There are no basis for (4) and (5).

Comment: @iammilind :  i vaguely remember that somewhere i had read gita verse - in which 'Krishna says that he himself is shiva'. That verse is not quoted there

Comment: You may have confused that verse with "I am Shankara among Rudra-s". I have added that verse now. However, Shiva and Shankara are different. Refer this [Are Lord Shiva and Lord Shankar two different deities?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2278/1049)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If Brahman is everything, then why does Krishna (Brahman) describe himself as "best of things" in Bhagavadgita?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11090/if-brahman-is-everything-then-why-does-krishna-brahman-describe-himself-as-b)

Answer (score 4):

Lord Krishna is Vishnu! Arjuna uttered this while looking at the universal form.

> Chapter 11, Verse 24
>
> O all-pervading **Visnu**, I can no longer maintain my equilibrium. Seeing
>   Your radiant colors fill the skies and beholding Your eyes and mouths,
>   I am afraid.
>
> Chapter 11, Verse 30
>
> O **Visnu**, I see You devouring all people in Your flaming mouths and
>   covering the universe with Your immeasurable rays. Scorching the
>   worlds, You are manifest.

Arjuna also saw Brahma and shiva in universal form of visnu.

> Chapter 11, Verse 15
>
> Arjuna said: My dear Lord Krsna, I see assembled together in Your body
>   all the demigods and various other living entities. I see Brahma
>   sitting on the lotus flower as well as Lord Siva and many sages and
>   divine serpents.

At another place he says that there is no one superior to him, in other words he is the cause of all causes.

> Chapter 7, Verse 7
>
> O conquerer of wealth [Arjuna], there is no Truth superior to Me.
>   Everything rests upon Me, as pearls are strung on a thread.

Comment: Shiva is wrong translation Jha Saheb. Arjuna said: My dear Lord Krsna, I see assembled together in Your body all the demigods and various other living entities. I see Brahma sitting on the lotus flower as well as Lord Siva and many sages and divine serpents.

Comment: You better check Sanskrit before pasting here.

Comment: @Rajas. Siva and shiva are different? the actual verse calls him "isam"

Comment: @Rajas. Just like vishnu is called visnu, shiva is called siva too that extra h sound is not needed.

Comment: Only Vaishnava philosophers have translated that Shiva because being Vaishnava. In reality, Arjuna saw kAl & he saw only Brahma there.

Comment: @Rajas. Well kal is different in different sects, in vaishnavaism he is subservient to Vishnu and is also a manifestation of vishnu for destruction.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Shiva: In which verse of gita, krishna
>   has declared either that krishna is "shiva"
>   or declared that "shiva" origiates from
>   him?
>
> Replace shiva with rudras.

We will start from the verse of
bhagwat geeta :-

> I am Marichi among the Maruts,
>   and the Moon among
>   constellations. I am the Sama
>   Veda among the Vedas; I am
>   Vasava among the gods; I am the
>   mind among the senses; I am the
>   intellect in (living) beings. I am
>   Sankara among the Rudras.
>
> —— The Mahabharata, Book 6:
>   Bhishma Parva: Bhagavat-Gita
>   Parva: Section XXXIV (Bhagavad
>   Gita Chapter X)

It says that among eleven rudras
krishna is shankar as there are
eleven rudras and all have
different name mahabharat gives
an account of two types of eleven
rudras one from harvamsa parva
and one from mahabharat. Before
it was kapalin who was best among
rudras now according to bhagwat
geeta he is shankar who is best
among rudras thats why krishna
says among rudras i am shankar.
For proof click here :- https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudras

clicking here you can
knoledge abou rudras.
Some would be thinking how there
are these much rudras ok some
time it is called kalpa-bheda
(diffences because kalpa of which
it is mentioned.)

Ok here is the proof that will clear
it:-

> Eleven hundred Rudras stood
>   around that Deity of restrained
>   soul and white deeds, then seated
>   upon his bull. All of them were
>   employed in hymning his praises.
>   The Adityas, the Vasus, the
>   Sadhyas, the Viswedevas, and the
>   twin Aswins praised that Lord of
>   the universe by uttering the hymns
>   occurring in the scriptures.
>
> —— The Mahabharata, Book 13:
>   Anusasana Parva: Anusasanika
>   Parva: Section XIV

So here eleven hundred rudras are
mentioned.

And here is some more proof:-

> O son of Pritha, flowed from this
>   Krishna who is Vishwaksena. The
>   Rudras, the Adityas, the Vasus, the
>   Aswins, the Sadhyas, the
>   Viswedevas, the diverse Maruts,
>   Prajapati himself, the mother of
>   the deities, viz., Aditi, and the
>   seven Rishis, have all sprung from
>   Krishna.
>
> — The Mahabharata, Book 13:
>   Anusasana Parva: Section CLVIII

now

> Likewise the Maruts are the
>   foremost of the Ganas. Surya is the
>   lord of all the planets, and
>   Chandramas of all the
>   constellations. Yama is the lord of
>   the Pitris; Ocean is the lord of all
>   rivers. Varuna is the king of the
>   waters. Indra is said to be the king
>   of the Maruts. Arka is the king of
>   all hot bodies, and Indra of all
>   luminous bodies. Agni is the
>   eternal lord of the elements, and
>   Vrihaspati of the Brahmanas. Soma
>   is the lord of (deciduous) herbs,
>   and Vishnu is the foremost of all
>   that are endued with might.
>   **Tashtri is the king of Rudras , and
>   Siva of all creatures.**
>
> **—— The Mahabharata, Book 14:
>   Aswamedha Parva: Anugita Parva:
>   Section XLIII**

And here we can see that Tashtri
is the king of rudras and shiva lord
of all creatures.

But it is not just for rudras see
this verse from bhagwat geeta :-

> I am Vishnu among the Adityas
>
> **——The Mahabharata, Book 6:
>   Bhishma Parva: Bhagavat-Gita
>   Parva: Section XXXIV (Bhagavad
>   Gita Chapter X)**

Some people say that shiva is in
the vishwrupa of krishna but it is
false because in vedas rudra is
praised as having vishwrupa.

Here it is :-

> **namo virupebhyo
>   vishvarupebhyashcha vo namo**
>
> Salutations to you who assume
>   grotesque and monstrous forms
>   and other diverse shapes.
>
> **—— sri rudram,anuvaka 4**

And in mahabharat also tells what
is vishwrupa and declares that
shiva is also known as vishwrupa.
Here it is :-

> Since by all his acts he performs
>   sacrifices for all and seeks the
>   good of every creature, therefore he
>   is called Siva or the auspicious
>   one. Staying above (in the sky) he
>   burns the lives of all creatures and
>   is, besides, fixed in a particular
>   route from which he does not
>   deviate. His emblem, again, is fixed
>   and immovable for all time. He is,
>   for these reasons, called Sthanu.
>   He is also of multiform aspect. He
>   is present, past, and future. He is
>   mobile and immobile. For this he
>   is called Vahurupa (of multiform
>   aspect). **The deities called
>   Viswedevas reside in his body. He
>   is, for this, called Viswarupa (of
>   universal form).**
>
> **——The Mahabharata, Book 13:
>   Anusasana Parva: Section CLXI**

And yes the reason people call him
inside the vishwrupa of krishna is
because acharyas like
madhavacharya and
ramanujacharya gave promenency
to the word 'isham' which is an
adjective for bramha as bramha is
lord of creatures. Rather than that
they say that the isham is shiva.
Although isham is between bramha
and his lotus seat.
Here is the verse from bhagwat
geeta.

> अर्जुन उवाचपश्यामि देवांस्तव देव
>   देहेसर्वांस्तथा भूतविशेषसङ्घान्।
>   ब्रह्माणमीशं कमलासनस्थमृषींश्च
>   सर्वानुरगांश्च दिव्यान्।।11.15।।
>
> Arjuna said: My dear Lord Krishna,
>   I see assembled in Your body all
>   the demigods and various other
>   living entities. I see Brahma sitting
>   on the lotus flower, as well as Lord
>   Shiva and all the sages and divine
>   serpents.

Here the line means——"bramha
who is lord of creatures is sitting
on his lotus seat.
This translation is also refferd by
the founder of advait vedant" - adi
shankaracharya.

And also the famous translation of
full vyasa mahabharat by kisari
mohan gaungoli which is on sacred
texts.com also writes this :-

> "Arjuna said, 'I behold all the
>   gods, O God, as also all the varied
>   hosts of creatures, (and) Brahman
>   seated on (his) lotus seat, and all
>   the Rishis and the celestial snakes.
>   I behold Thee with innumerable
>   arms, stomachs, mouths, (and)
>   eyes, on every side, O thou of
>   infinite forms. Neither end nor
>   middle, nor also beginning of thine
>   do I behold, O Lord of the
>   universe, O thou of universal form.
>
> —— The Mahabharata, Book 6:
>   Bhishma Parva: Bhagavat-Gita
>   Parva: Section XXXV (Bhagavad Gita
>   Chapter XI)

And other translations of bhagwat
geeta on the famous website
sacred texts.com done by scholar
also does not show shiva in
vishvrupa of krishna.

> Here are those links :-
>
> http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbg/index.htm
>
> http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/gita/index.htm

Here,some may be thinking that
what is the matter here? Why
some include shiva in krishna
vishvrupa and some do not include
it.

The reason is the word 'isham'.

> The line - ब्रह्माणमीशं
>   कमलासनस्थमृषींश्च सर्वानुरगांश्च
>   दिव्यान्।।11.15।।
>
> Here bramhaisham
>   kamalsansthmrishech

Here the word 'isham' is reffered
as shiva. As they think ish as
shiva.

Yes the word ishwar refers to shiva
and  the word maheshwar means -
great ishwar. The word ishan also
refers to shiva. But only ishan has a
connection with word isham.
So,Ishan means the ruler, the god
who rules the world. The lord of
the universe.

And Isham means rulership or
lordship over the unverse.
Here ist the proof :-

> "——Duryodhana said, "After the
>   fears of those throngs of the pitris,
>   the gods, and the Rishis had thus
>   been dispelled by that high-souled
>   Deity, Brahman then offered his
>   adorations, unto Sankara, and
>   said these words for the benefit
>   of the universe, ——**Through thy
>   favour, O Lord of all, the
>   Lordship of all creatures is mine.
>   Occupying that rank, I have given a
>   great boon to the Danavas.** It
>   behoveth none else, save thee, O
>   Lord of the Past and the Future, to
>   destroy those wicked wights that
>   show no regard for any one. Thou
>   O god, art the only person
>   competent to slay the foes of these
>   denizens of heaven that have
>   sought thy protection and that
>   solicit thee. O lord of all the gods,
>   show favour to these. Slay the
>   Danavas, O wielder of the trident.
>   O giver of honours, let the
>   universe, through thy grace, obtain
>   happiness. O Lord of all the
>   worlds, thou art the one whose
>   shelter should be sought. We all
>   seek thy shelter.
>
> **—— The Mahabharata, Book 8:
>   Karna Parva: Section 34**

Now

> 2) Vishnu: In which verse of gita , krishna
>   has declared either that krishna is "vishnu"
>   or declared that "vishnu" origiates from
>   him?
>
> I am Vishnu among the Adityas
>
> **——The Mahabharata, Book 6:
>   Bhishma Parva: Bhagavat-Gita
>   Parva: Section XXXIV (Bhagavad
>   Gita Chapter X)**
>
> 3)Brahma: In which verse of gita, krishna
>   has declared either that krishna is
>   "brahma" or declared that "brahma"
>   origiates from him?
>
> "Arjuna said, 'I behold all the
>   gods, O God, as also all the varied
>   hosts of creatures, (and) Brahman
>   seated on (his) lotus seat, and all
>   the Rishis and the celestial snakes.
>   I behold Thee with innumerable
>   arms, stomachs, mouths, (and)
>   eyes, on every side, O thou of
>   infinite forms. Neither end nor
>   middle, nor also beginning of thine
>   do I behold, O Lord of the
>   universe, O thou of universal form.
>
> —— The Mahabharata, Book 6:
>   Bhishma Parva: Bhagavat-Gita
>   Parva: Section XXXV (Bhagavad Gita
>   Chapter XI)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73018/discussion-on-answer-by-fierce-lord-in-which-verse-of-gita-krishna-has-declared).